# Android OnTouchListener for incrementing a value doesn't stop when touch ceases

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is the code for the OnTouchListener:

```
launchableSelectionView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE,100)
            {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l)
                {
                    MissileSystem system = bFittedToPlayer ? game.GetOurPlayer().GetInterceptorSystem() : game.GetSAMSite(lFittedToStructureID).GetInterceptorSystem();
                    int lFreeSlots = system.GetEmptySlotCount() - Types.size();
                    int lAvailableFunds = game.GetOurPlayer().GetWealth() - lTotalCost;

                    if (lFreeSlots == 0)
                    {
                        activity.ShowBasicOKDialog(context.getString(R.string.insufficient_slots));
                    }
                    else if (lAvailableFunds < game.GetConfig().GetInterceptorCost(type))
                    {
                        activity.ShowBasicOKDialog(context.getString(R.string.insufficient_funds));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        launchableSelectionView.IncrementNumber();
                        AddType(type.GetID());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {

                }
            };

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
            {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            countDownTimer.start();
                        }
                    }, 750);
                }
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This code is for players to purchase missiles.

**What I want it to do** is increment the number of missiles to purchase when the user long-presses the button after .75 seconds, and cease incrementing the number when the player lifts their finger.

**What it does instead:** If the user taps the button, it will wait .75 seconds and then begin incrementing the number as though the user were still touching the button. (Before I added PostDelayed, it would begin incrementing the number immediately, and not stop.)

Comment: Unless the user holds their finger down for over 750 milliseconds, you will be trying to `cancel()` the `CountDownTimer` before you call `start()` on it.

Comment: @CommonsWare It seems that .cancel() is not working at all, as if a player touches the purchase button but doesn't hold it, it will start incrementing the number after 750 milliseconds. Why is .cancel() not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be using a `android.os.Handler` to intercept the `java.lang.Runnable` before it can ever run. After that, ditch the `CountDownTimer` altogether.

```java
//Recreate a Handler over and over again.
Handler hand=new Handler();
Runnable run=new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    MissileSystem system = bFittedToPlayer ? game.GetOurPlayer().GetInterceptorSystem() : game.GetSAMSite(lFittedToStructureID).GetInterceptorSystem();
    int lFreeSlots = system.GetEmptySlotCount() - Types.size();
    int lAvailableFunds = game.GetOurPlayer().GetWealth() - lTotalCost;

    if (lFreeSlots == 0)
    {
      activity.ShowBasicOKDialog(context.getString(R.string.insufficient_slots));
    }
    else if (lAvailableFunds < game.GetConfig().GetInterceptorCost(type))
    {
      activity.ShowBasicOKDialog(context.getString(R.string.insufficient_funds));
    }
    else
    {
      launchableSelectionView.IncrementNumber();
      AddType(type.GetID());
    //Increment every 1ms
    hand.postDelayed(this, 1);
}};

hand.postDelayed(run, 750);
//To intercept if user just didn't held on long enough.
hand.removeCallbacks(run);
```

Comment: Looks good. Where should I put this in my code? When I try to put in in the OnTouchListerner I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: Figured it out. Your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @TheBiscuit Whoops SO notifications came in too late, but I am glad you figured it out. Welcome!